# Passing 2 variable from view to contoller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have a part of view like this:

```
 <?php 
                        echo form_open("sales/complete/", array('id'=>'finish_sale_form', 'autocomplete'=> 'off')
                    ); ?>

<li class="list-group-item">
                                <?php
                                    echo '<label id="project_start_date_label" for="project_start_date">';
                                    echo lang('sales_project_start_date');
                                    echo ':</label><br />';
                                ?>
                                <div class="input-group date datepicker2" data-date="" data-date-format=<?php echo json_encode(get_js_date_format()); ?>>
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                        <?php echo form_input(array(
                                                            'name'=>'project_start_date',
                                                            'id'=>'project_start_date',
                                                            'value'=> $tgl1? DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', substr($tgl1,0,10))->format(get_date_format()) : '',
                                                            )
                                                        );?> 
                                                      </div>
                            </li>

                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <?php
                                    echo '<label id="project_end_date_label" for="project_end_date">';
                                    echo lang('sales_project_end_date');
                                    echo ':</label><br />';
                                ?>
                                <div class="input-group date datepicker2" data-date="" data-date-format=<?php echo json_encode(get_js_date_format()); ?>>
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                        <?php echo form_input(array(
                                                            'name'=>'project_end_date',
                                                            'id'=>'project_end_date',
                                                            'value'=> $tgl2? DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', substr($tgl2,0,10))->format(get_date_format()) : '',
                                                            )
                                                        );?> 
                                                      </div>
                            </li>
?>
```

and i have controller sales.php with code like this:

```
function complete()
{

    $project_start_date = $this->input->post('project_start_date'); //the result is empty
    $project_end_date = $this->input->post('project_end_date'); //the result is empty
}
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is to pass the value of datepicker of project_start_date and project_end_date to be accepted in controller...

Please help what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the html input generated properly. If it has the correct name, and ID. Next, make sure the value being selected is correct by adding a JavaScript method to display selected values for example you can add. 
'onclick'=>'dislpay(this);' to your array and in your scripts section add:

function display(this){ alert(this.value); }.

The last thing I can think of is to make sure you have form_close . Hope this helps.